# Some help on a Java program to draw a rainbow

Tags: java, swing, draw, background-color

I'll be candid about this; it is a homework assignment, but can someone guide me in the right direction and explain to me how some parts of the code are supposed to work? The directions are below the code and the questions.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Rainbow extends JPanel
{
  // Declare skyColor:
     private final Color skyColor = Color.CYAN;

  public Rainbow()
  {
    setBackground(skyColor);
  } 
  // Draws the rainbow.
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
super.paintComponent(g);
int width = getWidth();    
int height = getHeight();

// Declare and initialize local int variables xCenter, yCenter
// that represent the center of the rainbow rings:
int xCenter = width/2;
int yCenter = (height * 3) /4;

// Declare and initialize the radius of the large semicircle:
  int largeRadius = width/4;

g.setColor(Color.RED);

// Draw the large semicircle:
 g.fillArc(xCenter,yCenter,largeRadius,height,0,180);
// Declare and initialize the radii of the small and medium
// semicircles and draw them:
int smallRadius = height/4;
 g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

 g.fillArc(xCenter,yCenter,width,height,0,180);
 int mediumRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(smallRadius * largeRadius);
 g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
 g.fillArc(xCenter,yCenter,width,height,0,180);


// Calculate the radius of the innermost (sky-color) semicircle
// so that the width of the middle (green) ring is the
// arithmetic mean of the widths of the red and magenta rings:


// Draw the sky-color semicircle:
 g.fillArc(xCenter,yCenter,width,height,0,180);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
JFrame w = new JFrame("Rainbow");
w.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 200);
w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container c = w.getContentPane();
c.add(new Rainbow());
w.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

My questions:  How exactly does fillArc work; I understand what goes in the parameter, but what must one do so each arc differs from one another?
How does one set one color for each arc?  I tried doing so, and I ended up with the color listed closest the end showing up and overriding the others.
I'll probably have more as a I continue to code.

These were the directions:

![enter image description here][1]

The “rainbow” is made of four overlapping semicircles. The outer ring is red (Color.RED), the middle one is green (Color.GREEN), and the inner ring has the magenta color (Color.MAGENTA). The innermost semicircle has the same color as the background.

Follow the instructions below and fill in the blanks in Rainbow.java.

1. Start the Rainbow project.
2. Add a complete comment header with your name before the class declaration at the top of the file.
3. Add to the Rainbow class a declaration of a private final field skyColor of the type Color, initialized to Color.CYAN (the color of the sky). In Rainbow’s constructor, set the window’s background to skyColor rather than Color.WHITE.
4. In the paint method, declare local integer variables xCenter and yCenter that represent the coordinates of the center of the rings. Initialize them to 1/2 width and 3/4 height (down) of the content pane, respectively. (Recall that the origin of graphics coordinates in Java is at the upper left corner of the content pane with the y-axis pointing down.) Do not plug in fixed numbers from the window’s dimensions.
5. Declare a local variable largeRadius that represents the radius of the largest (red) semicircle and initialize it to 1/4 of width.
6. A method call g.fillArc(x, y, size, size, from, degrees) (with all integer arguments) draws a sector of a circle. x and y are the coordinates of the upper left corner of the rectangle (in this case a square) into which the oval is (logically) inscribed; size is the side of the square (and the diameter of the circle); from is the starting point of the arc in degrees (with 0 at the easternmost point of the horizontal diameter), and degrees (a positive number) is the measure of the arc, going counterclockwise. Add a statement to the paint method to draw the largest (red) semicircle. Test your program.
7. Add statements to display the medium (green) and small (magenta) semicircles. The radius of the magenta semicircle should be 1/4 of height. The radius of the green one should be the geometric mean (the square root of the product) of the radius of the red semicircle and the radius of the magenta semicircle, rounded to the nearest integer. (A call to Math.sqrt(x) returns the value of square root of x, a double.) Retest your program.
8. Add statements to display the innermost semicircle of the background (“sky”) color to complete the rainbow. Use the skyColor constant for this semicircle’s color. Choose the radius of the sky-color semicircle in such a way that the width of the middle (green) ring is the arithmetic mean of the widths of the red and magenta rings.
9. Test your program.
10. Submit your completed program and run output. Your run output (the rainbow picture) can be included by capturing the screen output (Alt-PrintScrn), pasting it into a graphics program (such as MS Paint) and then saving the image to your Eclipse project directory.

    ```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Rainbow extends JPanel
    {
      //Declare skyColor:
        private final Color skyColor = Color.CYAN;

      public Rainbow()
    {
    setBackground(skyColor);
    }

     // Draws the rainbow.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int width = getWidth();    
    int height = getHeight();

    // Declare and initialize local int variables xCenter, yCenter
    // that represent the center of the rainbow rings:
    int xCenter = width/2;
    int yCenter = (height * 3) /4;

    // Declare and initialize the radius of the large semicircle:
      int largeRadius = width/4;

    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    // Draw the large semicircle:
     g.fillArc(xCenter - largeRadius,yCenter - largeRadius   ,largeRadius,largeRadius,0,180);
    // Declare and initialize the radii of the small and medium
    //semicircles and draw them:
     int smallRadius = height/4;
     int mediumRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(smallRadius * largeRadius);
     g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
     g.fillArc(xCenter-(largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2,yCenter-          (largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2,mediumRadius,mediumRadius,0,180);
     g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
     g.fillArc(xCenter-(largeRadius+smallRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+smallRadius)/2,smallRadius,smallRadius,0,180);




    // Calculate the radius of the innermost (sky-color) semicircle
    // so that the width of the middle (green) ring is the
    // arithmetic mean of the widths of the red and magenta rings:
       int skyRadius = (int)((2 * Math.sqrt(smallRadius * largeRadius)) - width/4);

    // Draw the sky-color semicircle:
     g.setColor(skyColor);
     g.fillArc(xCenter-skyRadius,yCenter-skyRadius,skyRadius,skyRadius,0,180);

     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
    JFrame w = new JFrame("Rainbow");
    w.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 200);
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c = w.getContentPane();
    c.add(new Rainbow());
    w.setVisible(true);
     }
    }
    ```

Comment: The contrast of colors on your screenshot is making my eyes hurt ...

Comment: Do you have a question about something specific that you don't understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fillArc() fills in a section of the circle based upon the parameters you gave it. For example your first arc.

You're drawing the fill arc, which in this case is a semi-circle, of the color red.

```
//Set the arc color
g.setColor(Color.RED);

// Draw the large semicircle:
g.fillArc(xCenter,yCenter,largeRadius,height,0,180);
```

[image: circle]

There's our fillArc. That doesn't look anything like a rainbow. In order to get the rainbow shape, we have to draw a smaller arc inside of it. In your case the next one is green. So we do fillArc again after setting the color to green. But we shrunk the radius a little bit so the green doesn't cover the entire red section.[image]

Keep in mind when we draw, we're drawing on top, so if you drew the green on first it would be covered by the red one.

Then we draw another arc inside this once more, but make this one the color of the sky (white in this case). This creates the final rainbow shape. So we do fillArc again, but with a slightly smaller radius and the color white.

[image: rainbow!]

And there, we drew a rainbow.

To center this beautiful creation, we have to understand a few things about the fillArc function.

The parameters are:

```
public abstract void fillArc(int x,
           int y,
           int width,
           int height,
           int startAngle,
           int arcAngle)
```

int x and int y represent the coordinates for the upper left hand corner of the arc that you are drawing. The reason your code isn't centering is because of how you're drawing the arc.

```
g.fillArc(xCenter - largeRadius,yCenter - largeRadius,largeRadius,largeRadius,0,180);
g.fillArc(xCenter-(largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2,mediumRadius,mediumRadius,0,180);
g.fillArc(xCenter-(largeRadius+smallRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+smallRadius)/2,smallRadius,smallRadius,0,180);
```

I took out a few of the excess stuff. You see how you're subtracting the (largeRadius+smallRadius)/2 and (largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2? This is shifting the rainbow to make it off center. What you should have is instead:

```
g.fillArc(xCenter - largeRadius/2,yCenter - largeRadius,largeRadius,largeRadius,0,180);
    g.fillArc(xCenter-(mediumRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2,mediumRadius,mediumRadius,0,180);
    g.fillArc(xCenter-(smallRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+smallRadius)/2,smallRadius,smallRadius,0,180);
```

This will properly center the rainbow. Here's why.

[image]

That's the point where they will start the drawing the arc from. If you want to center the entire rainbow, you'd shift it over by half of it's entire width. So if you want to center the red arc, you'd do

```
xCenter - (largeRadius/2)
```

As this is setting the x start to the left by half. You wouldn't include largeRadius in the other arcs, as you're centering them around this point. Thus you'd want to shift them over by half of their individual widths, which is why their x positions are

```
xCenter-(mediumRadius)/2
xCenter-(smallRadius)/2
```

Centering on the Y-axis works differently. You have to consider that the height of the rainbow overall is 1/4 the largeRadius. Your code uses yCenter = 3/4 * height, so that changes it a bit.

This is my solution

```
g.fillArc(xCenter - largeRadius/2,yCenter - largeRadius/2 + largeRadius/4 -height/4,largeRadius,largeRadius,0,180);
g.fillArc(xCenter-(mediumRadius)/2,yCenter-(mediumRadius)/2 + largeRadius/4 -height/4,mediumRadius,mediumRadius,0,180);
g.fillArc(xCenter-(smallRadius)/2,yCenter-(smallRadius)/2 + largeRadius/4 -height/4,smallRadius,smallRadius,0,180);
```

Let's take a look. I subtracted the largeRadius/2 (and respective radiuses) for the same principle as in x. But then I added largeRadius/4 because we have to shift the entire rainbow down. This is because subtracting the respective radius/2 only centers the rainbow as if it were an entire circle, not semi-circles.

Adding largeRadius/4 shifts the rainbow down by overall half of it's height, centering it correctly for a semi-circle. Finally, subtracting height/4 makes changes the yCenter to height/2, since 3/4 * height is a requirement in your assignment.

Sorry about all the problems in the comments, hope this cleared it up.

Comment: Is the purpose of xCenter and yCenter just to locate the point on the screen where the drawing will start?

Comment: Think of xCenter and yCenter as the center of the circle that the semicircle is from.

Comment: I finished most of the rainbow, but I'm having trouble getting the innermost part to fit the conditions: Add statements to display the innermost semicircle of the background (“sky”) color to complete the rainbow. Use the skyColor constant for this semicircle’s color. Choose the radius of the sky-color semicircle in such a way that the width of the middle (green) ring is the arithmetic mean of the widths of the red and magenta rings. I'll post my updated code in the question.

Comment: Actually I think the other answer covered have to draw the sky radius.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Do you know why the rainbow is a bit off to left on the screen when I run the program?  Is this just a problem in int xCenter = width/2; ?  I changed the function to xCenter = (width * 29)/48; and got it in the center.  The directions, however, told me to use 1/2 the width and they somehow had the rainbow in the center using 1/2 as opposed to another value.

Comment: I'm probably asking you way too much at this point, but why is it that doing y-Center-(arcRadius)/2 (for all the arcs) puts my rainbow near the bottom?

Comment: Remember that the coordinate plane works in that y is smaller near the top, and larger near the bottom. So a smaller y value (e.g. 0) is actually higher up on the screen than a larger y value (e.g. 100). Thus in y, you will want to add instead of subtract.

Comment: yCenter+(smallRadius)/2 I did such a format for the other arcs and the rainbow appears as a distorted blob at the bottom of the screen. Is there something wrong with the (smallRadius)/2 part (for all arcs)?

Comment: Ignore what I said before, I was being a dummy, sorry! The height is different because that's the semi circle part right? So the height has already been divided in half, so you'd have to divide it in half again.

Comment: I'm doing something like that y-Center-(arcRadius)/2 for all arcs but its at the bottom of the screen.  yCenter-(largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2 for all arcs (placing largeRadius meidumRadius smallRadius at respective places) yields a rainbow closer to the center but still not centered with respect to the y-axis.  x-axis is centered after using the xCenter - radius/2

Comment: I should be apologizing to you for asking all those questions, the problems in the comments helped be understand the effect of doing certain things in java.  Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified part of your code so you could get an idea. Remember that your xCenter and yCenter represent the center of your circle, not the coordinates you need to use in the fillArc method. The instructions you provided explain it pretty well. You can get an idea from what I did here and figure the rest by yourself.

```
// First declare and initialize all radiuses
  int largeRadius = width/4;
  int smallRadius = height/4;
  int mediumRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(smallRadius * largeRadius);

//Then draw each arc in descending order from the largest one

g.setColor(Color.RED);

g.fillArc(xCenter-largeRadius,yCenter-largeRadius,largeRadius,largeRadius,0,180);

g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

g.fillArc(xCenter-(largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+mediumRadius)/2,mediumRadius,mediumRadius,0,180);

g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

g.fillArc(xCenter-(largeRadius+smallRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+smallRadius)/2,smallRadius,smallRadius,0,180);

// Calculate the radius of the innermost (sky-color) semicircle
```

For you skyRadius consider:

> 1. Red width = large radius - medium radius
> 2. green width = medium - small
> 3. magenta width = small radius - skyradius

if I did the math rightyou get: skyRadius = smallRadius - 2*(mediumRadius-smallRadius)+largeRadius-mediumRadius

```
int skRadius=smallRadius-2*(mediumRadius-smallRadius)+largeRadius-mediumRadius;
 g.setColor(skyColor);
 g.fillArc(xCenter-(largeRadius+skRadius)/2,yCenter-(largeRadius+skRadius)/2,skRadius,skRadius,0,180);
```

Answer (score -1):

A much simpler equation for `skyRadius` is:

```
int skyRadius = largeRadius - 3 * mediumRadius + 3 * smallRadius;
```